# XNA model texture maps

Tags: xna-4.0, models

Is it possible to make a texture maps for XNA .fbx models? Just one texture file for the whole model.

Comment: You really only want to know *if it's possible*? You don't think you'll have any follow up questions with that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Formats vary greatly, although the content pipeline can handle a lot of situations.  Here are some stumbling blocks:

- Modeling software will segregate textures by material, or mesh, ect.  To unify them, you'll need to merge those somehow to use a single texture (while using the default `Model` class)
- 3DSMax will not package textures into the model by default.  It will
  save references.  You'll need separate texture files available for loading from the content project.
- Model references will usually contain absolute path information.  This confuses the importer when it copies content into the project's content folder, let alone from one developer's computer to another.
- Having path information *at all* is unnecessary.  XNA will chain-load texture and shader assets simply by referencing their file names in material/texture nodes of the model.
- These textures are loaded directly into the properties of the built-in `Model` class.  They do not need their own `Texture` objects.  The texture properties can be reassigned to other loaded assets at run-time.

It is good to remember that the default `Model` class was an imperfect solution to a very difficult problem.  Almost any deviation from the most basic usage requires a lot of infrastructure and cumbersome work.  It's probably still worth it to do, rather than trying to make other workflow pieces fit into that class.  [Shawn Hargreaves (XNA lead) posted a long summary of all the considerations that went into designing it, and all the reason why you might not like it.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/09/19/note-to-self-model-hammer.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make textures for .fbx files. Probably the easiest is to export a texture from whatever app you are using. For example here is a Blender example: http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/4614.aspx.